# jQuery Dynamic Add Form Field, Remove Form Field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

Hello I am trying to add new form field and delete form field after getting inspired from this tutorial - http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/dynamic-form-fields

My Current Problem is to delete and reset the value of all in chronological order.

```
<input type="hidden" name="count" value="1" />
<div class="control-group" id="fields">
           <label class="control-label" for="field1">Nice Multiple Form Fields</label>
           <div class="controls" id="profs"> 
             <div class="input-append">
               <input autocomplete="off" class="span3" id="field1" name="prof1" type="text" placeholder="Type something (it has typeahead too)" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8" 
data-source='["Aardvark","Beatlejuice","Capricorn","Deathmaul","Epic"]'/><button id="b1" onClick="addFormField()" class="btn btn-info" type="button">+</button>
             </div>
             <br /><small>Press + to add another form field :)</small>
           </div>
         </div>
```

Javascript :-

```
var next = 1;

function addFormField(){
    var addto = "#field" + next;
    next = next + 1;
    var newIn = '<br /><br /><input autocomplete="off" class="span3" id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8"><button id="b1" onClick="$(this).parent().remove();" class="btn btn-info" type="button">+</button>';
    var newInput = $(newIn);
    $(addto).after(newInput);
    $("#field" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
    $("#count").val(next);  
}
```

Parent Element is getting removed, but next counter is not reset properly. in hidden and all new created form :-

Only Add Demo :- http://bootsnipp.com/snipps/dynamic-form-fields

Add an Delete Demo with Bug :- http://jsfiddle.net/6dCrT/2/

Can someone help me please.

Thanks

Comment: It seems, the only problem with http://jsfiddle.net/6dCrT/2/ that when deleting does not removing <br>, resulting a lot <br>, thus leaves space before the last form input field.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
function addFormField(){
    var addto = "#field" + next;
    next = next + 1;
    var newIn = '<br /><br /><input autocomplete="off" class="span3" id="field' + next + '" name="field' + next + '" type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-items="8"><button id="b'+next+'" onClick="$(this).prev().remove();$(this).remove();" class="btn btn-info" type="button">-</button>';
    var newInput = $(newIn);
    console.log(addto);
    $(addto).after(newInput);
    if(next>1)
        $("button#b"+next).after(newInput);
    $("#field" + next).attr('data-source',$(addto).attr('data-source'));
    $("#count").val(next);  
}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6dCrT/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: but field value is not getting reset. after adding 3 field and deleting 2 other.. next field still comes with number 'field4' :(

Comment: @JohnyBravo Why do you want to change element attributes like id,name on fly? You can still parse the parent div for all inputs inside.

Comment: Excuse my noobness, and can you please explain what do you mean ?

Comment: Why do you want to reset next field? If you reset next field you need to reset element id's in the html to make sure that you dont have duplicate id's.

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I was building a form that would allow users to add multiple input names if they had more than one dog.

```
    var counter = 0
    jQuery(function () {
      $(".newDog").click(function(){
        counter ++;
        if (counter < 4) {
          var elem = $("<input/>",{
            type: "text",
            name: `dogname${counter}`
        });
        } else {
          alert("You can only add 4 Dog Names")
        }
        
        var removeLink = $("<span/>").html("X").click(function(){
            $(elem).remove();
            $(this).remove();
            counter --;
        });
        
        $(".dogname-inputs").append(elem).append(removeLink);
    });
    })
```

Full credit as mentioned to https://stackoverflow.com/users/714969/kevin-bowersox