# How to do dynamic form design using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have designed a web page in such a way that there are a left sidebar and right side white space to design a form.
How can I achieve the below functionality:
When the user clicks on textbox button at the left sidebar at the right side white space there should one text box should be display with a close mark
if the user clicks on any form element at right side space the respective form element should be deleted.
there should one clear button if the user clicks on the clear button

fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/t4uqc58w/1/

```css
   #sidebar-wrapper {
      max-width: max-content;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/css/simple-sidebar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class="d-flex" id="wrapper">
    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div id="page-content-wrapper">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light border-bottom">
        <!--<button class="btn btn-primary" id="menu-toggle">Preview</button>-->
        <h1>Free Form Design</h1>
      </nav>
      <div class="container-fluid">
      </div>
      <!-- Sidebar -->
      <div class="bg-light border-right" id="sidebar-wrapper">
        <div class="list-group list-group-flush">
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            <input type="button" value="TextBox" />
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            <input type="button" value="TextArea" />
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            <input type="button" value="Checkbox" />
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            <input type="button" value="Radio button" />
          </div>
          <div class="list-group-item list-group-item-action bg-light">
            <input type="button" value="DropDown" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
  </div>
```

Comment: What javascript have you tried to accomplish this? You should post it here as SO isn't a code writing service.

Comment: As i am beginner i am looking for the approach thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery Dynamic Add Form Field, Remove Form Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18952410/jquery-dynamic-add-form-field-remove-form-field)

Comment: Without an example of the jquery you're already using it is not possible to help.